# How to instantiate an Optional Node from my Information Model into my OPC UA Server ( .Net Environement)

Tags: .net, opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

I am a beginner in OPC UA server development. I am working on .NET environment to create an server with my own Information Model which is created on UAModeler.

when I instantiate the nodes available in my information model, only those which are set as Mandatory are successfully instantiated. I am trying to find a way how can I instantiate the remaining nodes also which are by purpose set as Optional for Modeling rule.

Below snippet of my code from Node Manager class :

`Console.WriteLine("Loading the Im 2.1 Model.");
ImportUaNodeset(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), "informationmodel_2.0.xml");
Console.WriteLine("IM Sucessfully Loaded");

```
            CreateObjectSettings settings = new CreateObjectSettings()
            {
                ParentNodeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder,
                ReferenceTypeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ReferenceTypeIds.Organizes,
                RequestedNodeId = new NodeId("IM", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                BrowseName = new QualifiedName("Departments", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                TypeDefinitionId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ObjectTypeIds.FolderType

            };
            ObjectNode controllersNode = CreateObject(Server.DefaultRequestContext, settings);

            settings = new CreateObjectSettings()
            {
                ParentNodeId = controllersNode.NodeId,
                ReferenceTypeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ReferenceTypeIds.Organizes,
                RequestedNodeId = new NodeId(DepartmentA, DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                BrowseName = new QualifiedName(DepartmentA, DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                TypeDefinitionId = new NodeId(My.MyIm.ObjectTypes.BodyshopProductionEquipmentType, DefaultNamespaceIndex)

            };

            CreateObject(Server.DefaultRequestContext, settings);
            
            ProductionDataNode = FindInMemoryNode(new NodeId(DepartmentA + ".ProductionData", DefaultNamespaceIndex)) as VariableNode;
            CounterPerTypeNode = FindInMemoryNode(new NodeId(DepartmentA + ".ProductionData.CounterPerType", DefaultNamespaceIndex)) as VariableNode;`
```

any suggestions or similar solved examples would be highly appreaciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with the unified-automation-sdk but in the OPCFoundation Stack you have to create the nodes manually.

This is typically done in `CreateAddressSpace` method of Node Manager class, see [Boiler example](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/blob/cf9ae6f16b0ca8bbbed156f636e8d9f1674e7630/Workshop/Boiler/Server/BoilerNodeManager.cs#L127).

*Modelling Role optional indicates that the server has to decide if the creation is required or not.*